# The meaning of "as i live and breathe"

Tags: american-english

As it is used when meeting someone for whom you havent met for ages.

Is this mean that the speaker is emphasizing or wandering if he/she is alive to see this?

Answer (score 2):

**as I live (and breathe)**. [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/11307#eid38321883)

> used to express emphatic affirmation of the truth of something; later
>   frequently also expressing surprise at an event or situation

Your question:

> Is this mean that the speaker is emphasizing or wandering if he/she is
>   alive to see this?

No. The sense is more like one of great surprise ... like "well, blow me down!'

Comment: "As sure as I'm alive, it's Fred Bloggs!", meaning that it really is him although you would never have expected to see him there.